# "ExecuteReader:Connection Property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LENOVO; Initial Catalog = MainData; Integrated Security = True");
        con.Open();

        string CheckID = "select StaffID from PersonsData where StaffID='" + txtStaffID.Text + "'";
        cm = new SqlCommand(CheckID);

        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Company Name Already Exists", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtStaffID.Text = "";
            txtStaffID.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] img = null;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            string Query = "insert into PersonsData (StaffID, FullName, Email, Address, Picture) values('" + this.txtStaffID.Text + "','" + this.txtFullname.Text + "','" + this.txtEmail.Text + "','" + this.txtAddress.Text + "',@img)";
                    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        con.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                    cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
                    int x = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + "Successfully Saved!");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

This is my code i don't understand why I'm getting this error:

> ExecuteReader:Connection Property has not been initialized.

I'm making a save button where the Staffid will be checked first if already.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Use `cm = new SqlCommand(CheckID, con);` to actually **assign** the connection to the command !

Answer (score 3):

Before executing the command, you need to say which connection is to be used. In your case, it is:

```
cm.Connection = con;
```

Take a note that, include this line of code after opening the connection and after creating the instance of SqlCommand.

Answer (score 2):

```
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = LENOVO; Initial Catalog = MainData; Integrated Security = True");
    con.Open();
    string CheckID = "select StaffID from PersonsData where StaffID='" + txtStaffID.Text + "'";
    cm = new SqlCommand(CheckID);
    cm.Connection = con; //Assign connection to command
```

You didn't assign connection to `SqlCommand` used in the reader

Comment: You are welcone @yvan .

Comment: can i ask another help if it's okay...... if not just ignore this....
"There is already an open DataReader Associated with this command which must be closed first."

Comment: add line `rdr.Close();` before `cm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough, You have to assign the connection for the Command, either through assignement or through the constructor, That is:

```
cm = new SqlCommand(CheckID);
cm.Connection = con; // Should be added
SqlDataReader  rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();
```

Or else you can use the constructor to initialize the command like this:

```
cm = new SqlCommand(CheckID,con);
```

Hope that you are aware of these things since you ware used it correctly in the else part of the given snippet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you assign the SqlConnection to your Command-Object. You can do this via Constructor or Property:

```
con = new SqlConnection(//Your Connectionstring)
//assign via Constructor
cm = new SqlCommand(CheckID, con);
//or via Property
cm.Connection = con;
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();
```

Further I would recommend you to use a using-block to make sure that the Command and Connection gets destroyed after using it.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection())
{
   using (var cm = new SqlCommand())
   {
   }
}
```